# Can't show table from mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I just migrated my database from my online webserver to localhost, including all pages where I hosted it..

The problem is the table wont show which is populated from mysql database, and I am struggling it for a day to get the solution. I thought the problem is the PHP version between my online webserver with my localhost is different. Then I moved the database and the pages to my laptop which is the PHP version is higher than the online webserver PHP version, and the problem is still appears.

I don't know whats wrong with my code, the page is doing well in my webserver. The connection.php is correct too.

This is the **code** of my page:

```
<?php
$hostname_localhost ="localhost";
$database_localhost ="a3647822";
$username_localhost ="root";
$password_localhost ="";
$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
or
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
$sql = "select * from paket";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
?>

bla
bla
bla until content

<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="1">
  <tr>
   <th>id</th>
   <th>Nama Paket</th>      
   <th>Keterangan Paket</th>
   <th>Harga</th>   
   <th>Set Menu</th>                        
   <th>Edit</th>                
  </tr>
    <?php while($paket = mysql_fetch_array($result)){?>
  <tr>
      <td><?php echo $paket['id_paket'];?></td> 
      <td><?php echo $paket['nama_paket'];?></td>       
      <td><?php echo $paket['keterangan_paket'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $paket['harga'];?></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkDel[]" id="checkboxx" class="aku" value="<?=$paket["id_paket"];?>"></td>
      <td><a href="edit_data_paket.php?nama_paket='.$paket['nama_paket'].'">Edit</a></td>                </tr>
    <?php }?>
</table>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Check whether $count is working or not? Try echo $count;

Comment: i rename .html tag to .php and its working, dont know why because on my online webserver its okay with .html tag..thanks for your attention..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the result line (12) to

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

To see if the query is throwing an error

Comment: nope..the page didnt show anything..i upload the screenshot of page source..the php code is appear with green color.if iam right the php code should didnt appear..

Comment: i rename .html tag to .php and its working, dont know why because on my online webserver its okay with .html tag..thanks for your attention..

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without knowing what the error is, but I think the problem is in this line:

```
<?php while($paket = mysql_fetch_array($result)){?>
```

You should be using:

```
<?php while($paket = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){?>
```

These 2 lines are almost definitely causing problems too:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="chkDel[]" id="checkboxx" class="aku" value="<?=$paket["id_paket"];?>"></td>
<td><a href="edit_data_paket.php?nama_paket='.$paket['nama_paket'].'">Edit</a></td>
```

Needs to be:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="chkDel[]" id="checkboxx" class="aku" value="<?php echo $paket["id_paket"];?>"></td>
<td><a href="edit_data_paket.php?nama_paket=<?php echo $paket['nama_paket'];?>">Edit</a></td>
```

Comment: i uploaded the screenshot of page source..the php code is appear with green color.if iam right the php code should didnt appear..